# What version of Ruby is included on OS X?

Tags: ruby, macos

I'm working with Ruby and want to target multiple versions of OS X.

What default version of Ruby should I expect to be preinstalled on updated versions of OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10.9.0: ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]

10.8.5: ruby 1.8.7     (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]

10.7.5: ruby 1.8.7     (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]

Comment: Thank you; would you mind quoting the source(s)?

Comment: I've had this hanging around for some time, I'm not sure where I got it from, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) comes with two Ruby versions, `1.8.7p358` and `2.0.0p247`:

```
$ ls /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions
1.8     2.0     Current

$ /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin13.0]

$ /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
```

The `ruby` command in `/usr/bin` defaults to 2.0.

Check out Marc-André Lafortune's [backports](https://github.com/marcandre/backports) gem if you are dealing with different Ruby versions:

> The goal of ‘backports’ is to make it easier to write ruby code that
>   runs across different versions of Ruby.